# Upgrade packages with pip from inside code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I saw an older question, suggesting to use pip.main(package), however this does not *upgrade* a package. I could not find anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should not be updating packages from inside code unless it is strictly necessary. It can cause incompatibility errors. You can use system calls though

Comment: @J. C. Rocamonde How would I go about using system calls?

Comment: I guess a better answer than mine solves the problem, but you can call the pip command with the python `subprocess` module

Comment: OK,  thanks. I looked at that, but it seemed I needed to enter the password many times because I was looping it to upgrade all, and python was in admin only folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pip.main(['install', '--upgrade', package])` instead. `pip.main` just takes arguments exactly like the command line version.

Comment: Shouldn't package go between quotes?

Comment: I was assuming `package` was a variable containing the name of whatever package OP wants to upgrade.

Comment: Yes, `package` was a variable that had a string inside it. Here is the class; `def pipInstall(package):
    pip.main(['install', '--upgrade', package])`

Comment: Did that do it for you then? It works on my machine.